# Make one MacBook Pro use the screen of another MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, screen-sharing, dual-screen

I have two MacBook Pros: a 2011 17 inch  and a 2017 15 inch; both have the latest macOS installed.

Does anyone know if it is possible to make the 15" MBP  use the 17" MBP as an external monitor?

Answer (score 10):

You can't *physically* connect the display of another MacBook (or any other laptop for that matter) to use it as an external monitor.

However, there is an app called [AirDisplay](https://avatron.com/applications/air-display/) that will turn *any* display into an external monitor via WiFi (or wired network if you prefer).

> Wirelessly connect to an iPad or Android device from your laptop to
>   create the ultimate road-warrior workstation. Or repurpose any nearby
>   Mac or Windows PC to give yourself more screen real estate for your
>   main Mac.

It's a pretty good piece of kit, but (IMO) it's better to just purchase an external monitor that meets your needs; it's much more stable, reliable, and better performing.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this Apple web site](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592), only the following iMac models offer Target Display Mode.

- iMac (27-inch, Late 2009)
- iMac (27-inch, Mid 2010)
- iMac (Mid 2011-Mid 2014)

There is no mention of any Mac Book Pro models that can be used as monitors.

Answer (score 1):

There's also regular AirPlay which is part of macOS Monterey now: https://www.macrumors.com/2021/06/09/airplay-mac-to-mac-external-display/